# Mockito MissingMethodInvocation - Mocking call method on object that has not been initialized

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, method-invocation

Can someone please provide me with a way to use Mockito to test the following piece of code? I am currently receiving a MissingMethodInvocation Exception.

```
obj1.getId().getString()
```

obj1 is a mocked object and the getId() method returns another object, obj2, with a getString() method. I have tried

```
@Mock private obj1
@Mock private obj2
Mockito.when(obj1.getId()).thenReturn(obj2);
Mockito.when(obj2.getString()).thenReturn("TEST STRING");
```

However, I receive the following error

```
<<< ERROR!
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.
   It is a limitation of the mock engine.
```

And trying

```
@Mock private obj1
@Mock private obj2
Mockito.when(obj1.getId().getString()).thenReturn("TEST STRING");
```

returns

```
<<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Thanks in advance for any help or references.

**SOLUTION**
obj2.getString() is a final method, which as the error readout says - 
"1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified."

My workaround is to set the string of obj2 -

```
@Mock private Obj1Type obj1
Mockito.when(obj1.getId()).thenReturn(obj2);
obj2.setString("TEST_STRING");
```

Comment: What type is "obj1" and "obj2"?

I believe you should have something like:
@Mock private MyThing obj1

Where "MyThing" is your type.

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] rather than pseudo-code? It would help us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: My bad I forgot to include the types in the example I posted but they're there. The mock lines have \@Mock private obj1Type obj1; and \@Mock private obj2Type obj2;